# Include CSS Files in Angular Package

Tags: css, angular, project.json

I am currently building a tarball npm package via npm:

```
npm run build-release
npm pack dist/
```

Afterwards, I use npm install xxx.tgz to install the package in another Angular application. This works fine to use components defined in the first package, but I also need to access .css files defined in the first project.

When I inspect the generated xxx.tgz there is not a single .css file from the project included. How do I tell npm to do so, so in a project installing this package can use varialbes defined in the packages .css files?

Answer (score 0):

CSS is compiled and bundled when you `ng build`.

To avoid that, you have to declare them as assets. This is done in the `angular.json` file (you should alreay have the `style.css` file in an array of assets).